# AppEngine performance settings missing

Tags: google-app-engine

I am trying to find the performance settings mentioned here [ https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/adminconsole/performancesettings ]

It describes a place where you can adjust your app engine performance settings in the console. (I want to keep an idle instance running on my app engine project.)

This seems to be describing the old developer console.

I tried using https://appengine.google.com/a/projectName to access this page but it seems I only have access to the new console.

Did the performance settings get removed completely or is there somewhere in the new console I can change these settings?

Thanks,
Nathan

Comment: This is annoying! It used to be very simple to change the performance dynamically with the old console, now even the old console doesn't allow it :( It mean I need to deploy my server again to change the performance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These performance settings, regardless of which console you are using are a thing of the past within the console.

The introduction of modules has moved this configuration to entries within a modules yaml file. EG:

```
application: sample
module: my-module
version: uno
runtime: python27
instance_class: F1
automatic_scaling:
  min_idle_instances: 1
  max_idle_instances: automatic  # default value
  min_pending_latency: automatic  # default value
  max_pending_latency: 30ms
```

App config: https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/config/appconfig

Modules: https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/modules/#Python_Instance_scaling_and_class

Answer (score 3):

The old developer console url is:

```
https://appengine.google.com/dashboard?app_id=s~[PROJECT_NAME]
```

Performance settings are configured within App Engine Modules.  More details are at:  https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/modules/#automatic_scaling_1